# Page transitions on page load

Tags: pageload, transition

I'm looking for a solution or someone to put me on the right track to have page transition effects on pages when they are loaded.

When a user loads a new page in the browser I'd like it to slide in from the left. I've seen this effect on one page websites but can't seem to find anything that works on multi page sites.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) should help you.

Comment: Perhaps using JQuyery?  http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/page-loading-effects-with-jquery/